# Show cart contents on onepage checkout 1.9.1

Tags: onepage-checkout, ce-1.9.1.0

I am using the RWD default theme, default installation. I've tried a lot of the methods mentioned in other Magento versions to show the cart contents on the onepage checkout in 1.9.1 but have yet to have any success.

The contents do show from the drop-down on-click cart, but would like to see a constant visible 'mini-cart' above or below the onepage checkout progress field. I've seen a lot of "onepage" checkout modules with this feature, but want to try and keep everything as 'core' as possible.

Comment: I added this to

app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/checkout.xml

And that put the cart into the page - many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and add the following code to

`app/design/frontend/YOURPACKAGE/YOURTHEME/layout/local.xml`

```
<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
    <reference name="right">
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/sidebar.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Put it just above the closing `</layout>` tag. This should display the minicart in the right sidebar above the progress field, like in the screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: I added a default local.xml file to the layout folder and added the code you provided and it works beautifully and I assume, is a better practice as well. Again, thank you.